# NSString is being returned as 'null'

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have this simple method for returning the file path. I am passing the file name as argument. Then when I call this method this method returns 'null' if running on device but works fine on simulator. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
-(NSString*) getFilePathForFile:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *temp = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return temp;
}

NSString *path = [self getFilePathForFile:@"settingInfo.plist"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you stepped through this method in the debugger? Surely you can get a clearer sense of where something is going awry?

Comment: I would add in some `NSLog` to see where things go sideways. `NSLog(@"fileName = %@", fileName);`, `NSLog(@"array = %@", array);`, `NSLog(@"documentsDirectory = %@", documentsDirectory);`, and `NSLog(@"temp = %@", temp);` should show you exactly where your issue is. This will make figuring out a fix much easier.

Comment: I have tried NSLog and it does print everything right when we are inside the method but when the value is returned, it is returned null. I dont understand why?

Comment: Show us the code with the NSLogs in and the output you get.  If the return value `path` is nil, clearly everything is *not* right inside the method.  There's no known bug in Objective-C where a return value gets zapped between the return statement and the caller assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some sort of memory management problem. Have you tried to use "Build and Analyze" to see if Xcode can pick up any memory problems?

Otherwise, try this and see if you get something non-null:

```
NSString *path = [[self getFilePathForFile:@"settingInfo.plist"] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that method can fail and not throw an exception is if the array returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is nil.  Check that a valid array is being returned.